# Does MoneyWell have a "jars" system?

Tags: software

Does MoneyWell have a "jars" system?

I imagine if I have PHP 1000, I want to be able to "give every peso a job" like place it in a "jar" for example. Then I want MoneyWell to track that "jar" for me, like if it's positive, I'm obliged to spend it (or transfer it to an untouchable savings account). If it's negative, it means I'm over the budget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is how moneywell works.

Every month or week depending on your salary period you allocate your income to buckets (which  think correspond to your jars) and then when you spend anything you take hat money from a bucket. If the bucket is positive you are in budget otherwise you had better work out where to cut your budget.

The buckets are your budget are are a different split to you accounts which show where all your money is saved etc.

See the [video tutorials](http://nothirst.com/tutorials/) for more examples.

Comment: Think of "Buckets" or "Jars" as the old time envelopes where you put XX amount of money "saved" for that. The program allows you to automatically fill the "jars" every month and allocate your money.